# Fetch Twitter Feed without logged in to Twitter

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

I am try to show my twitter feeds in my app using twitter api 1.1, I want its shows only my timeline every time so no need to user login. But twitter don't provide any tutorial or sample code to use their api Can any one suggest some good tutorial or sample code to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Guri.. Can u tweet on twitter without login.? Than hows it is possble without login.?

Comment: Thanks Shreyansh for reply but can you please provide me some tutorial or sample code to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You ll get from developer page of twitter.

Below I have mentioned link of it and also provide discussion of twitter.

[Twitter Developer page](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6998)

[Twitter Discussion](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5214)

Hope, This will help you.